# Generate Dictionary from nested List, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have below List:

```
dimensionList = [{'key': 2109290, 'id': 'R', 'name': 'Reporter', 'isGeo': True, 'geoType': 'region'}, 
         {'key': 2109300, 'id': 'C', 'name': 'Commodity', 'isGeo': False, 'geoType': None}, 
         {'key': 2109310, 'id': 'P', 'name': 'Partner', 'isGeo': True, 'geoType': 'region'}, 
         {'key': 2109320, 'id': 'TF', 'name': 'Trade Flow', 'isGeo': False, 'geoType': None}, 
         {'key': 2109330, 'id': 'I', 'name': 'Measure', 'isGeo': False, 'geoType': None}]
```

I want to create dictionary from this list

Need Values of 'id' as Id of dictionary & 'name' as Values of dictionary

Expected Results:-

```
ResultsDict = {'R':'Reporter', 'C':'Commodity', 'P':'Partner', 'TF':'Trade Flow', 'I':'Measure'}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `dict comprehension`:

```
d = {x['id']:x['name'] for x in dimensionList}
print (d)
{'R': 'Reporter', 'C': 'Commodity', 'P': 'Partner', 'TF': 'Trade Flow', 'I': 'Measure'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the list of dictionaries, pulling out the bits you want and adding them to your new dictionary.

```
ResultsDict = {}

for dict_item in dimensionList:
    id = dict_item ['id']
    name = dict_item ['name']
    ResultsDict[id] = name

print(ResultsDict)
```